# Merge html after using Ckeditor insertHtml function

Tags: ckeditor

i'm thinking about writing a function to merge the inserted Html with the surrounding tags. 
The thing is that i have used the ExtractContents(true) method. Which splits the selection from the document. And makes it Html valid again.

But now i revised and change the html.. and i would like to put it back.. but the 2 letters that i selected from the header will be shown below the first h1. in a new H1. This 2 H1's need to have the equal attributes and classes to merge..

But still couldn't think of an script that will do this.. any ideas or does somebody have this already?  Some helpfull functions maby?

EXAMPLE:

```
<h1>1234</h1><h1>56</h1>
```

The HTML that is inserted is the `<h1>56</h1>`.
Now i want to look before and after the inserted html if i can merge it with the tag that is before of after the inserted part..

This means that the inserted part can contain multiple tags.

This will result in:

```
<h1>123456</h1>
```

EDIT: Found this method: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-mergeSiblings

But is it possible to define if the merge to the left or to the right?
Or does someone know a way to do this? Because the elements are merging now. 
But if there are multiple `<p>` tags it will merge them all together. what not may happen.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution... Was looking for the wrong keywords..
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-mergeSiblings